# Azure Mobile app - Easy API versioning

Tags: node.js, azure, version, azure-mobile-services

We have been using Azure Easy API using Node.js for some of the mobile apps. Given the fact that the mobile apps stay in different versions, we need to have different versions of the same API available. In such a case, how do we carry out the versioning? Is there any azure documentation that someone can point to? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation on versioning for Azure Mobile Apps.  Internally, we use the ZUMO-API-VERSION to switch between protocols.  If you are using EasyAPI, then that is designed for the most simple cases - versioning of your API is not supported.

Instead of using EasyAPI, the site underneath is just a Node.js application.  Download it (via Kudu), check it into source code, and use regular old Express routing for your API.  You can then version it any which way you like.

If you need further information on versioning WebAPIs, I recommend [Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026617.do) - it's on ASP.NET, but covers a lot of the required semantics for versioning within it.

Comment: Thanks Adrian Hall